# How can I make function that waits for an asnyc function to finish before running?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Currently I have a async function that is using a fetch request to receive data once that data is received I want it to run checkVals right away. Only problem is that checkVals is running before my async function is finished. How can I have checkVals wait for the async function to finish before running?

Original Async

```
async function getData(quData) {
  let res = await fetch("http://localhost:9000/testAPI/api/upload", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "content-type": "application/JSON" },
  });
  data = await res.json();
  return (quData = {
    Title: data.Title,
    Question: data.Question,
    DoC: data.DoC,
  });
}
```

Original Async without fetch

```
const data = null
const quData = null

async function getData() {
  data = {
    Title: "Title",
    Question: "Question",
    DoC: "DoC"
  }
  return (quData = {
    Title: data.Title,
    Question: data.Question,
    DoC: data.DoC,
  });
}
```

Function to run after Async

```
const checkVals = () =>{
   console.log(quData)
}
```

The only thing I've tried checking for is if quData is a truthy value and it wasn't working.

Comment: `await` the function?

Comment: `getData().then(() => checkVals());` or `await getDate(); checkVals()`

Comment: @Yousaf that worked. Thanks, I'm kinda stupid.